# Python join string elements in separate lists then add lists together

Tags: python, data-structures

If I have two lists of individual string characters:

```
['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
['w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd']
```

How do I make the final outcome look like this below of one list and where all of the string characters are combined:

```
['Hello','world']
```

If I try something like this:

```
word1join = "".join(word1)
word2join = "".join(word2)

print(word1join,type(word1join))
print(word2join,type(word1join))

print(list(word1join + word2join))
```

I am recreating the original data structure again but incorrectly, any tips appreciated!

```
Hello <class 'str'>
world <class 'str'>
['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd']
```

Comment: Just create a new list with them in: `print([word1join, word2join])`

Comment: well that was easy if you post a answer ill hit the green check box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a new list with them in:

```py
word1 = ['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
word2 = ['w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd']

word1join = "".join(word1)
word2join = "".join(word2)

print([word1join, word2join])
```

Output as requested

Answer (score 0):

If your variable names have numbers in them, it's usually a good hint that you should better be manipulating one list, rather than several individual variables.

Instead of starting with two variables:

```py
word1 = ['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
word2 = ['w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd']
```

Start with one list:

```py
words = [['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'], ['w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd']]
```

You can still access individual words using indexing:

```py
print(words[1])
# ['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
```

You can then apply operations to every element of that list using `for`-loops, or list comprehensions, or function `map`:

```py
words_joined = [''.join(word) for word in words]
# ['Hello', 'world']

# OR ALTERNATIVELY
words_joined = list(map(''.join, words))
# ['Hello', 'world']
```

If you really need to split the list into two variables, you can still do it:

```py
word1joined, word2joined = words_joined

print(word2joined)
# world
```